# Как задать права для бд? Не могу найти. (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я хочу дать пользователю право на SELECT всех таблиц в базе данных. Единственное что я нашел то что можно задавать конкретно для одной таблице. Может кто-то знает как именно для всех таблиц в базе данных это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

`GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO some_user;`

Можно задать только для конкретной `SCHEMA`

[Документация](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-grant)